# Authorization in microservice architecture

Tags: scope, authorization, microservices

currently I develop a backend based on the microservice architecture.
Unfortunately, I have a problem how to realize the authorization.

So let me explaine my system - there are the following services:

- OAuth 2.0 Service (issuing JWT)
- Group Service
- Some Ressource Services (e.g. ToDos Service)

Every user is in one or many groups.
Each resource (like a ToDo list) also belongs to a group.
That means if some user creates a todo list, that list gets stored in the name of the group.

Szenario:

- User A is in group A
- User B is in group A and B
- User C is in group C
- User A creats a ToDo list in group A.
- User B modifies this ToDo list (he is allowed to do this since he is also in group A)
- User C also tries to modify this ToDo list, but he shouldn't allowed to do this since he is only in group C.

Has any body a great idea how I could realize this in a microservice architecture and keep the dependencies between the services on a minimum?

Certainly, I could ask on every request the Group Service if the user is in the group to which the resource belongs to. But so I get a really hard dependency between the Resource Services and the existence of a Group Service - I like to avoid this dependency.
Another option would be to store all groups, to which the user belongs to, in the access token. But with this option the client has to ask every time the OAuth Service for a new token when the user gets a member of a new group.

So is there any other option how I could realize this szenario?

Comment: By keeping the dependencies to a minimum I suppose you want your system to be more resilient, i.e. if Authorization MS fails then the ToDos MS should continue to work, am I write?

Comment: Yes, this is one thing. But this isn't really a problem. This could be easily solved with horizontal scaling the Group Service. Instead I like to supress the complete dependency between those two services.

Comment: Complete dependency removal is impossible.

Comment: Also, horizontal scaling does not solve cascade failure.

Comment: Instead I like to supress the complete dependency between those two services and keep the communication between services as low as possible - so I could get higher speeds - the service hasn't to ask every time the group service if the user is a member of this group. So my question goes in that direction, that I want to know if this could be solved on another way. Should I hold some member information on every resource server which depends on groups? Or is there another possible mechanism to get the authorisation working in this szenario?

Comment: Long story short: you need to keep a copy of the needed data on each dependent ms and then keep it up to date

Comment: There is no other way AFAIK

Comment: okay, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have three domains:

1. Authentication: responsible for identifying the user
2. Authorization: responsible for restricting access to resources
3. Todos: your core domain

You have done well identifying three [bounded contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html), one for each domain and implemented in three microservices (MS). You are conforming to the best practices regarding [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

No, your question is how could you integrate those three microservices in such a way that the system is [resilient](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/), i.e. its microservices continue to work even if some of the other microservices fail.

You have two options regarding integration (communication between microservices):

1. Synchronous communication: every time the Todos MS receive a request, it queries the Authorization MS to check if the user is permitted to do what it wants. This has the advantage that is simple to implement but it has the disadvantage that is susceptible to cascade failure: if the Authorization MS fails then this MS also fails. So, this option is not good for you.
2. Asynchronous communication: somehow in the background, there is some data that is replicated from the Authorization MS to the Todos MS. You have at least two options for this replication to be done: a) in [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [scheduled tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) or similar and b) using a [event driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture). This has the advantage that provides more resilience but it has the disadvantage that is more complex, harder to implement. **This option seems to fit your need**.

Further reading:

- [Building microservices](https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Building_Microservices_Nginx.pdf)

Comment: do you mean, access should be validated by the Todos MS ?

Comment: @Ngob ideally, in an API gateway

Comment: Is it safe to validate access business rules in the API gateway? Does that mean when I add a new feature associated with a access rule, I have to update the API gateway? Doesn't that break mean my domain will be break into multiple service?

Comment: @Ngob if by that you mean "authorization" then yes, it is *safe*, because authorization is not part of the domain

Comment: I am not sure we understand each others here. Im not talking about RBAC, If I simplify this example: "User C isn't allowed to update TODO of another user". Here I mean User C have the right to "update" a "TODO" but not to update a "TODO" from User A. From your answer I understand this kind of validation is done by the domain, but from your comment it looks like it does not belongs to the "TODO" domain. Your thought?
Thanks,

Comment: @Ngob no, it is not part of the domain. This checking should be done before the command reaches your domain; i.e. the Application service(or the API gateway) calls the Authorization service  to authorize the command and if it is permitted then it forwards it to the Aggregate.

Comment: Thanks you. So that would mean the authorization service is far more than a RBAC validation in most of case?!

Comment: @Ngob I think so, yes, because one must check if a user can do some action to a particular entity not only that he/she can perform that action in general.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put the authorisation handling into a API gateway. When there is an incoming request the following steps are executed

1.The API gateway hits the OAuth server to get a transparent token which contains the access roles and groups of the user 
2.The API gateway then calls the to do services with the access token , which the to do services use to decide if a particular user is authorised.

The advantage of this integration pattern is that the individual services don’t have to call the group service to get the roles.